# Import only point features with osm2pgsql using style file

Tags: postgresql, postgis, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I am very new `osm2pqsgl`. I have downloaded a `osm.pbf` file for all of Europe and I want to add this data to my `Postgres` database. However, I am only interested in `points`, no `linestrings` nor `polygon`, and within the `points` I am only interested in these tags and its information (like `denomination`, or `name`)

- Natural https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:natural
- Historic https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:historic
- Heritage https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:heritage
- Religion https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:religion
- Tourism https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:tourism

I have edited the `style` file from `osm2pgsql` down to this

```
node,way   historic     text         polygon
node,way   natural      text         polygon 
node,way   religion     text         linear
node,way   tourism      text         polygon
```

1. How to import only `Point` features from a `osm.pbf` file with `osm2pgsql`?
2. How to import only `Point` features with a specific `tag`, like `tourism` from a `osm.pbf` file with `osm2pgsql`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the `flex output` option from `osm2pgsql` and created a `.lua` file. Here with the `tag` `religion`.

```
local tables = {}
    
-- this creates the table for point and its columns
tables.religion = osm2pgsql.define_node_table('religion_point', {
    { column = 'osm_type',     type = 'text', not_null = true },
    { column = 'name',     type = 'text', not_null = true},
    { column = 'geom',     type = 'point' },
}, { schema = 'public' })

-- tags we don't need
local function clean_tags(tags)
    tags.odbl = nil
    tags.created_by = nil
    tags.source = nil
    tags['source:ref'] = nil

    return next(tags) == nil
end

function osm2pgsql.process_node(object)
    -- We are only interested in religion details
    -- replace here with the tag you want to import i.e. natural, historic, ...
    if not object.tags.religion then
        return
    end

    clean_tags(object.tags)

    -- Using grab_tag() removes from remaining key/value saved to Pg
    local osm_type = object:grab_tag('religion')
    local name = object:grab_tag('name')
    tables.religion:add_row({
        osm_type = osm_type,
        tags = json.encode(object.tags),
        name = name,
        geom = { create = 'point' }
    })
end
```

And then run it with

```
$ osm2pgsql -c -d <DATABASENAME> -U postgres -H localhost -O flex -S ./<NAME>.lua ./<FILENAME>.osm.pbf
```

Sources for the Script

- https://github.com/rustprooflabs/pgosm-flex
- https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql-website/blob/master/_manual/06-flex-output.md

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if `osm2pgsql` can do it on the fly, however you can use [osmosis](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis) for filtering the input files. Another option would be [osmium](https://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/).

On the other way, I'm not sure if discarding polygons a'priori is a proper assumption. You can find a lot of `tourism`, `religion` etc. tags on buildings (or other polygons). I would suggest to calculate centroids for them and `union` them together.

Comment: Thanks for the late reply. How would I import only `Point` and `Polygon` features with the tag `tourism` and `religion`. How would I modify the `style file`

Comment: Modifying style will not help. I would suggest to filter only points and polygons with requested tags by `osmosis`. There is an [example usage](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis#Example_usage) and [detailed one](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Detailed_Usage_0.48#--tag-filter_.28--tf.29).

Comment: I'll look into it, thanks!